# How to work with huge numbers like 475aax

Tags: c#, android

I don't have a current problem with programming but I have a question how to so something because I think it would be interesting.

I think someone know the idle Android games like TapTycoon or Idle Miner Tycoon. The programms seem to work with great numbers. Sometimes they show it like 406e60, 438a, 38ax or 487ba

Does someone know if such programms work with normal double values and calculate the exponent to show the number in a user friendly format? Or do they use maybe Biginteger and they have a real precise number?

Maybe someone has a small example C# code snippet?

Comment: I´m not sure about 38ax, but the rest is just normal hex-format. You can store any information as hex. You should read about hexadecimal numberformat.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it isn't hex. It is more like a format if the normal specifiers like k, m, g are to small. The order is sometimes like 1, 1k, 1m, 1g, 1t, 1p, 1a, 1b, 1c, ... , 1x, 1ax

Comment: Sorry, but it´s impossible for us to guess what this data should reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[double (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double)

`±5.0 × 10^−324` to `±1.7 × 10^308`

You could use something like this (add pepper and salt to taste)

```
public static class MyExtension
{
   static readonly string[] _sizeSuffixes =
      { "", "k", "m", "g", "t", "p", "e", "z", "y" };

   public static string ToSize(this double value, int decimalPlaces = 1)
   {
      if (value < 0)  return $"-{ToSize(-value)}"; 

      var i = 0;
      while (Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces) >= 1000)
      {
         value /= 1000;
         i++;
      }

      switch (decimalPlaces)
      {
         case 0: return $"{value:N0}{_sizeSuffixes[i]}";
         case 1: return $"{value:N1}{_sizeSuffixes[i]}";
         case 2: return $"{value:N2}{_sizeSuffixes[i]}";
         default:return $"{value:N3}{_sizeSuffixes[i]}";
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
double d = 345345654345356546345456.456;

Console.WriteLine(d.ToSize(2));
```

**Output**

```
345.35z
```